# Angular | Creating an Observable Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

In Angular6, I'm creating an `Injectable` service. I'm trying to initialize 
an `Observable` in the `constructor`, see simplified code below.

**Problem:** The callback function of `Observable.create` is never executed, and there is no errors. Why is `console.log('authObserver created!')` never called?

```
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserLoginService implements OnInit{

  authObserver:Observer;
  authObservable:Observable;

  constructor() {
    this.authObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
      this.authObserver = observer;
      console.log('authObserver created!')
    });  
  }    
}

randomCallbackFunction(){
  this.authObserver.next("Button has been clicked");
}
```

Comment: `rxjs` version?

Comment: Version is ^6.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, i dont see any subscription happening. Observables work only after subscription. Try this

```
this.authObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
      this.authObserver = observer;
      console.log('authObserver created!')
    });
this.authObservable.subscribe()
```

You can see it working [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vzpqh9w2/)

Comment: Also, if you want to push a new value, the reference is wrong in the original code in the function randomCallbackFunction(), it would be:  
this.authObserver.next("Button has been clicked");

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That mistake was a typo when I simplified code to SO. Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe and keep and eye on correctly push new values through next:

```
/*
 Create an observable that emits 'Hello' and 'World' on  
 subscription.
*/
 const hello = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    observer.next('Hello');
    observer.next('World');
 });

 //output: 'Hello'...'World'
  const subscribe = hello.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btroncone/td5107he/).

Comment: In the `randomCallbackFunction` the `this.observer` is `undefined`. Apparently `Observer` uses lazy initalization, and I need to subscribe before its initialized.

Comment: this.observer is just wrong, try this.authObserver, where you save your reference to the observer